# Dynamically apply classes to angular custom form component

Tags: css, angular

I have a custom form component and I would to dynamically apply classes to it.

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { BaseInput } from './base-input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-control',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => TextControlComponent),
    multi: true
  }],
  styles: [':host { display: inline-block }'],
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="ctx.isEditing">    
    <input class="form-control"
    [value]="value"
    (change)="value=$event.target.value" (keyup)="value=$event.target.value" >
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!ctx.isEditing">    
    {{value}}
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class TextControlComponent extends BaseInput<string> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I apply bootstrap classes to the component in the html the container gets the classes applied and not the child html element

```
 <app-text-control formControlName="test" [ngClass]="{
        'is-valid' : test.valid && (test.dirty || test.touched)  ,
        'is-invalid' : test.invalid && (test.dirty || test.touched)  
      }" ></app-text-control>
```

class is-valid or is-invalid is applied to the app-text-control container html and not the inner input control. Is there a way to propogate the ng-class classes that are set in the parent to the child html?

I want to be able to dynamically attach classes to the html on the  control inside my custom component, ideally using ngClass directive if possible. Do I have to write a custom attribute (e.g.[myNgClass]=.... )for this to work on my parent custom form  control?

Comment: does anybody know if it is possible to dynamically assess the classes set on a parent component which would also fulfil this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best way to do it, but you could do it this way :

```
<app-text-control formControlName="test" [isvalid]="test.valid && (test.dirty || test.touched)" [isinvalid]="test.invalid && (test.dirty || test.touched)" ></app-text-control>
```

And inside the child component you would have these `isvalid` and `isinvalid` properties which you can use with `ngClass`.

Comment: that might be the only way I can do it, ideally I wouldn't want to code for extra possible classes that I may want to set in my custom form control (I would need one attribute for every class I want to potentially add) but it's my best bet so far!!

Comment: You can also set up a property for the class name but then you would need to update it every time the `test` object changes... Not optimal.